# An App ID with Identifier X is not available

Tags: xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile, app-id

When ever I try to create an App ID it gives me this error:

[image: Error]
And I have no idea why. That is the bundle ID in xCode for my app. I have a feeling it's to do with the provisioning profile xCode makes? As it says:

[image: Provisioning Profile]
Does anyone know how to fix this? If I change my app ID when I'm creating it to be something that isn't my bundle ID it works just fine..?

Comment: I believe the bundle ID you are trying to use for your app is already taken by a different apple developer account.  Did you switch dev accounts?  Each bundle ID must be unique, so if some other dev account has that bundle ID registered, you are out of luck and will need to choose a different one.

Answer (score 0):

It happens some times when you try to add application before adding bundle identifier.

You can add bundle identifier and then try to refresh iTunesConnect page and try to add app this way it can solve your problem.

If still problem doesn't solve then try to open iTunesConnect after adding bundle identifier.

Comment: So I have the app already live in the App Store (so in ItunesConnect). It's not possible for me to register the app in developer.apple.com as an app id. You were able to fix this problem?